# Simply just adding a border of a different colour to a shape in edit mode

Tags: modeling, color

It's incredible that I cannot seem to find a way of just simply colouring in the edges/verts differently to the colour of the faces of the shape. It ought to be simple right? And then... being able to just raise the thickness level on the line of the edge...
[image]

How do you do it?

Comment: Please provide information about your problem. Your question is unclear - the title mentions edit mode, but the rest of the question seems to be about rendering. It is unclear what result you are after and in what context.

Comment: Hello Martin Z. Thank you for responding. Maybe I am not sure how to word the question... All I want to know is how to get thick border edges in edit mode, just like the picture above I uploaded where the edge of the faces are a different colour to the faces... ok? I hope what I said is comprehensable

Comment: you can do it with different ways, the easiest is to create edge loops close to the angle of your cube so that it makes thin borders, then you assign to these borders a different color than the rest of the cube.

Comment: To put it another way... I should be allowed to put more than one colour on one face, and make the secondary colour a thick borderline

Comment: thanks moonboots...although you may have to expand on your explanation if you don't mind helping me :D

Comment: i looked into loopcuts and tbh I don't want to do more cutting than I have to

Comment: If you're referring to the general appearance of edges of a selected mesh in edit mode, you should look into theme customization, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

I see at least 3 solutions. Note that if you want no shadow on your yellow, use an Emission shader:

**1/** Create **edge loops** close to your angles, and assign your yellow color to all these edges.

**2/** Duplicate your cube and give it a **Wireframe modifier**. Play with the parameters to increase or decrease the thickness of the wireframe.

**3/** In Photoshop, create a picture with a blue square and yellow outlines. In the UV/Image Editor of Blender, open this picture, unwrap your cube and give it a material with an **Image Texture node**, with the cube picture as the image.

[image]

Comment: #4... Freestyle?

Comment: yes but I don't know anything about it so I let you give that answer  ;)

Comment: you are legends!!!!!

Comment: wireframe solution: You don't need to duplicate it. Just add 2 material to it and in wireframe modifier: material offset -> give it a 1 and it get's the second material you add for the cube

Answer (score 2):

**#4 ... Freestyle**

- In <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, Edge menu > Edge Data, mark selected edges 'Freestyle'
- In the Properties > Render tab, check the 'Freestyle' box
- In the Properties > Render Layers tab > Freestyle Line Set, set 'Visible' and check 'Marked Edges' only, and with the default Line Set active...
- In the Properties > Render Layers tab > Freestyle Line Style, set the Thickness and Color

[image]

.. bearing in mind this is a post effect, so you won't see it in the viewport, only in a full render.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but since I'm not able to write comments I have to do it as an answer.
What about making a duplicate (Shift + d) and then putting a wireframe onto it? If you want the border to be a flat colour than use an emission shader on it only.

Comment: You don't need to dupllcate it. Just add 2 material to it and in wireframe modifier: material offset -> give it a 1 and it get's the second material you add for the cube